# iOS / XCode Auto Layout Woes. Easier Way?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, layout, constraints

I'm wondering if xCode auto layout / constraints are really as frustrating as I think, or am I just not understanding them.  For example, I started with this basic label in the view controller:

[image: initialController]

Fair enough.  A box with text that has equal margins on the left/right and a smaller top margin.  Now when I run any size device, that gets skewed/cut off from the device view.  So right away for some reason Xcode thinks that despite me putting the entire label in the view controller, it things it should display halfway off the screen.  Don't get it but okay, so I went ahead and added auto layout constraits to the right, left and top margins.  The result is:

[image: withMargins]

So it centered it, which is nice, but now it just ignores the fact that I made the width larger and it just shrinks it down anyways?  For something so simple this seems to be very...unreliable.  I then added the "aspect ratio" constraint and it seemed to look fine in all of the devices...finally!

I curiously also simply tried to get rid of all those, and simply add the "aspect ratio" constraint and the "horizontal center in container" constraint.  On the main storyboard preview (not the simulator) it looked like this:

[image: aspectAndHorizontal]

Not what I'm looking for, as it's not stretched downward like I want, they shrunk it again.  However...when actually running it in the simulator...it looks perfect, the way I want it to in the first picture of the view controller.

Why the preview and simulator differed, I suppose (from reading other questions) it's because there were a few warnings after I added these.  One was that the horizontal and vertical positions are one initially and will be different at run time.  But when I ran it, it definitely held the initial ones and not the ones they said it would be at run time.  It also told me that vertical position was ambiguous...well yeah I only set a center and aspect ratio...pretty obvious and not sure how I'd even solve that error.  It solves it when I delete the horizontal center...but now it's not centered which is a step back from what I wanted.

Long story short, how do I deal with this.  My previews and simulations aren't accurate with each other even for the simplest auto layout specifics.  Apps nowadays are so complicated and on every device they scale and work beautifully, and this seems to not agree with even just one label.

Does anybody have any good articles, advice, or anything that would help me?  This auto layout stuff seems to be so picky and that's really all I know so I have to deal with it.  And don't even get me started on why the text doesn't scale with the label...why would I want the text on an iphone 4 to be the same on an ipad even when my label is increasing in size with the device?

A lot to go through, but it's just very frustrating and I can't see myself doing much else before I try to understand these basics.  Thank you and much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to understand constraints first...without that you always made things frustrating....For understand the constraints you can check this links
http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1 
http://mathewsanders.com/designing-adaptive-layouts-for-iphone-6-plus/

Comment: Thanks!  I'll check these out.

Answer (score 1):

It takes a bit of experience to get used to it, but once you get it, you get it for good and it's very easy.

Basically the rule of thumb is don't trust exactly what you see in storyboard when it comes to the size of the actual object. Say you have a `UIView` centered horizontally and vertically in the main view.  True it will try to keep the size of that `UIView` but center it in any size device, but I would never just leave it at that. I would either:

1. Add width and height constraints
2. Add a width/height constraint and an aspect ratio constraint
3. Add a width constraint and top and bottom constraints
4. Add a height constraint and leading and trailing constraints
5. Add top, bottom, leading, and trailing constraints

In other words, the exact size of the object should *always* be determined via the constraints, and not by the UIView itself.  This gets away from the finicky behavior and also ensures that it's displayed on any device exactly the way you intend it to.